# How to run faye and rails as separate process in heroku?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku, ruby-on-rails-3.2, redis, unicorn

I have a rails app with `faye` as middleware and now i need to use `unicorn` to the rails app and i wanted to use `redis` with faye as i need to scale the `dynos` in `heroku`. I wanted to know how i can run the rails and faye as `separate process` in the same app.

Can i able to keep two `.ru` file and run those two in the same app. If yes, then i know i can run the rails app as

```
run Sample::Application
```

but how about running the faye?

```
var faye      = require('faye'),
    fayeRedis = require('faye-redis');

var server = new faye.NodeAdapter({
  mount:    '/faye',
  timeout:  45,
  engine:   {
    type:   fayeRedis,
    host:   'localhost',
    port:   6379
  }
});
```

Is this alone is enough?

How about starting those from the procfile as unicorn needs to be run from there?

Please help me.